Incorrect result of iferror formula via Apps Script
One of my line in google apps script function is next
mnmaSheet.getRange(9,22).setFormulaR1C1("=IFERROR(MATCH(R[0]C[-1!D:D,0);-1)")
However, after running the script result is incorrect because I always receive -1 even if the searched value is present in the sheet "Довідник".
I tried to write two brackets from both sides of sheet's name (''Довідник''), however I receive error. In addition, I tried to write codes for updating cells however it didn't work too.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a sheet sample.
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Hi Lime! I think the rest code or sheet may unnecessary confuse you. When I make minimal changes to formula after script (e.g., add space to end or replace "=" with "=", the formula works well then. So I suppose the problem is either in provided line of code or peculiarities of setting formula via apps script

Can you try using setFormula(formula) instead of setFormulaR1C1(formula) to see if it'll work?

Hi Saddles! It works, thank you!

Let me go ahead and rephrase my comments to be an answer to this question since you mentioned that It works. That way, other community members who stumble upon this post may know this information. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it as well.

Changing setFormulaR1C1(formula) to setFormula(formula) works since The given formula must be in R1C1 notation. for it to work.
The formula =IFERROR(MATCH(R[0]C[-1!D:D,0);-1) has arguments that are in A1 notation, which is why it was returning -1.
